# Copying Custom Color Formatting Down a Row

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, gs-conditional-formatting

I've read about five different answers on this here but they don't work in 2019 (or I'm an idiot doing something wrong). I want the cell in the N column to turn green or Red based on the data from O. However, I want N2 to look at O2, N3 to look at O3...

When using the "Paste Custom Format" option it increases the range of which the formula is applied to but it doesn't change the results and will condition all the rows based on O2. When I add $ signs it doesn't make a difference either.

The only option I saw to solving this was adding separate rules for each row which is obviously timely and a ton of manual labor.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

in the conditional formatting rules, mark custom formula is and paste:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(N2:N36=O2:O36,1,0))
```

Answer (score 0):

I was actually having the same problem today, I swear it used to work if you copied the formatting but I could be mistaken. In my sheet I have a column (T) where a formula can change the value to "WARNING", when it does I need the cell to turn red and the text to turn white. In the next cell to the right (column U) there is a checkbox, if that is then checked (a warning was issued) the cell with "WARNING" should turn white and the text to black. Here is what I did, one conditional formatting rule like this that turns the red, white text:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(T14:T48="WARNING",1,0))
```

and another like this to turn the cell white, text to black:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(U14:U48=TRUE,1,0))
```

Now when I copy and paste the conditional formatting it no longer references the original cell where I set it up but the cell I pasted it into. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

try like this:

red color custom formula:

```
=$O2<$P2
```

green color custom formula:

```
=$O2>$P2
```

[image: 0]